# Running kivy on python 3.7

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7

here is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix import label

kivy.require("1.11.1")


class EpicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return label(text="Hey there!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EpicApp().run()
```

here is the Error

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Robert\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-03-16_49.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\Interface\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\Interface\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/Interface/venv/Chatappforphone.py", line 14, in <module>
     EpicApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\Interface\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/Interface/venv/Chatappforphone.py", line 10, in build
     return label(text="Hey there!")
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i have been busting my head for about an hour now, trying to get this to work. hopefully someone here can lend me a hand

Answer (score 0):

label is the module and `Label` is the class of label.
so, try importing with `Label`.

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class EpicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hey there!")
```

Comment: problem is, now it says that module not found:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.uix.Label'